# Second iterative of find_elements_by_xpath gives error in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to find all the my subject in my dashboard of my college website.
I'm using selenium to do it.
The site is a little slow so first I wait

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='multiline']")))
```

then I find all the elements with

```
course = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='multiline']")
```

after that in a for loop I try to traverse it the 0th place of the "course" works fine and I'm able to click it and go to webpage but when the loop runs for the secon d time that is for the 1st place in "course" it gives me error  ***selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document***

So I tried adding a lit bit wait time to using 2 method it  still gives me error

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='multiline']")))
```

the loop

```
for i in course[1::]:

#driver.implicitly_wait(20)

#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='multiline']")))

print(i)
i.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

driver.back()
```

a snippet of the website

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `implicity_wait()` sets default terminate time. It does not used like pause. If you want code to stop of 2 secs, you need to use `time.sleep(2)` with importing `time` module.

Comment: its not about waiting time but not being able to find an item that is clickable as "element is not attached to the page document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after extensive research

A common technique used for simulating a tabbed UI in a web app is to prepare DIVs for each tab, but only attach
one at a time, storing the rest in variables. In this case my code have a reference
to an element that is no longer attached to the DOM (that is, that has an ancestor which is "document.documentElement").

If WebDriver throws a stale element exception in this case, even though the element still exists, the reference
is lost. You should discard the current reference you hold and replace it, possibly by locating the element again
once it is attached to the DOM

```
for i in range(len(course)):

    # here you need to find all the elements again because once we
     leave the page the reference will be lost and we need to find it again
    course = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='multiline']")

    print(course[i].text)
    course[i].click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    driver.back()
```